# Componente Composto em C# não mostra todos os atributos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Tenho um sistema no qual uso um `dataGridView` para listar os campos de uma tabela através da propriedade `dataSource`, e um `textBox` para que o texto escrito sirva de filtro (quando digito algo no `textBox`, uso o texto digitado para filtrar minha tabela e atualizo no `dataSource` do `dataGridView`).

Estou aprendendo C# e vi que no Visual Studio, posso criar um Componente Composto e quis criar um componente unindo o `textBox` e o `dataGridView`.

Iniciei a criação com um `dataGridView` e um `textBox` e gerei o novo componente (`textBoxGrid`).

Incluí o novo componente (`textBoxGrid`) no meu form e quando fui procurar a propriedade `dataSource` no novo componente, ela não é mostrada.

Como faço pra que ela fique visível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve criar um "link" entre a propriedade do seu `datagridview` e do seu componente.

Algo semelhante a isto:

No seu componente basta criar uma propriedade com `get`, e `set` apontando para a propriedade do `datagridview`:

Se você tiver necessidade de setar o `DataSource` em design mode, deve-se adicionar os atributos na propriedade.

```
[AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource)), DefaultValue(null), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
public Object DataSource
{
    get { return datagridview1.DataSource; }
    set { datagridview1.DataSource = value; }
}
```

Veja com o atributo na propriedade, o `datasource` é "desbloqueado"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembre-se que toda vez que alterar o componente deve-se dar `build` no projeto novamente para atualizar.

Comment: vou testar agora mesmo. posso fazer isso com qualquer propriedade?

Comment: Sim pode fazer isto com qualquer propriedade, inclusive você pode abrir o `get` e `set`, para manipular como quiser, inserindo  `if`, por exemplo.

Comment: Você carrega o `DataSource` no design do `visual studio` ou em tempo de execução?

Comment: Deu certo!!! Muito obrigado mesmo. Carrego no design.

Comment: Se você for carregar no design talvez seja necessário adicionar os atributos na propriedade. Como é object vai aparecer a propriedade mas não vai ser possível alterar. Vou alterar a resposta.

Comment: blz, aguardo voce alterar

Comment: obrigado, se não for pedir muito, você pode me explicar essa linha? -> [AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource)), DefaultValue(null), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50161/discussion-between-marco-giovanni-and-italo-rodrigo).